# Infinitesimal transformations of fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, action, variational-calculus

We usually want to study the infinitesimal transformations on the action which depends on the field $\phi(x)$ and its derivatives. Such transformations may in general be written as,

\begin{equation}
x'^\mu = x^\mu + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta x^\mu}{\delta \epsilon_a}\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}

where {$\epsilon_a$} is a set of infinitesimal parameters. This leads to the field infinitesimally transforming as,

\begin{equation}
\phi'(x') = \phi(x) + \epsilon_a \frac{\delta F}{\delta \epsilon_a} (x)\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation}

where $F$ is the function relating the new field $\phi'$ at $x'$ to the old field $\phi$ at x such that $\phi'(x') = F(\phi(x))$.

My issue is I don't understand why $\eqref{1}$ is written in that way. Why is there a variation term present? Plus, shouldn't it be a partial derivative instead? Of course, my question extends to $\eqref{2}$.

What I'm thinking is that, as in Taylor series, if we have a function $f(x)=f(a+\epsilon)$ where $a$ is fixed and $\epsilon$ is the variable (in this case $\epsilon$ is not necessarily small as in the usual convention where we use $\epsilon$ to denote something small, but I used it here as an analogy to the question), if we set $\epsilon=0$ we then get the function at $a$ which is $f(a)$. In general, if we do an expansion we set $\epsilon \neq 0$. To first order, we get $f(x) = f(a+\epsilon) = f(a) + \frac{df}{d\epsilon}\Big|_{x=a} \epsilon$.

Going back to the question, we can view $x'$ as a function of $\epsilon$ where $x$ is fixed, i.e., $x'(y) = x'(x+\epsilon)$. Doing a first order expansion as in the Taylor series, we get $x'(x+\epsilon) = x'(x) + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial \epsilon}\Big|_{y=x} \epsilon$. Here $x'(x)$ is $x'$ evaluated at $x$ which is of course just $x$, i.e., $x'=x$, so that
$x'(x+\epsilon) = x + \frac{\partial x'}{\partial \epsilon}\Big|_{y=x} \epsilon$. Sloppily, we can write $\frac{\partial x'}{\partial \epsilon}\Big|_{y=x} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \epsilon}$.

Now, instead of differentials, we can always demand a virtual displacement depending on what we are studying so that $x'(x+\epsilon) = x + \frac{\delta x}{\delta \epsilon} \epsilon$. Putting back the indices, we get the $\eqref{1}$. Can anyone comment on this?

Reference:

[Conformal Field Theory by Philippe Francesco , Pierre Mathieu , David Sénéchal](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=keUrdME5rhIC&printsec=frontcover&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), p. 39, eq. 2.125
[Lectures on Conformal Field Theory by Joshua D. Qualls](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04074), p. 25, eq. 2.17

Comment: The transformations that you want can only deal with rigid translations. What if you want to deal with rotations?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I'm not sure what exactly you mean, but couldn't $x'^\mu = x^\mu + \epsilon^\mu$ derive a relation for rotations? On the other hand, I know equation $(1)$ is correct so I'm asking how to derive it.

Comment: No, it cannot. For rotations, the change has to be proportional to where the particle currently is; in particular, if it is twice as far from the point of rotation, then the translation due to the rotation is twice as large. Your choice imposes that all the translations are the exact same size. It will never work. As for the derivation, you might refer to many other textbooks on the subject.