# Is It Functional Derivative in Transformation?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

In section 2.4 of *Conformal Field Theory* by P.D.Francesco, and others, it has discussed the infinitesimal transformation on spacetime and field,
$$x'^{\mu} = x^{\mu} + \omega_{a}\frac{\delta x^{\mu}}{\delta \omega_{a}}$$
$$\Phi'(x') = \Phi(x) + \omega_{a}\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta \omega_{a}}\tag{2.125}$$
Here $\{\omega_{a}\}$ is a set of infinitesimal parameters. And the appearance of $\frac{\delta x^{\mu}}{\delta \omega_{a}}$ and $\frac{\delta \mathcal{F}(x)}{\delta \omega_{a}}$ seems unfamilar to me. What do they mean? Are they just partial derivative w.r.t $\omega_{a}$ or they are functional derivative?
PS. I don't think it would be the latter one because $x^{\mu}$ seems unlikely to be functional, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/795811/2451

Comment: The just denote generators of the specific transformation. Whether or not they are derivatives depends on the particular case.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus So if we would like to compute these quantity, we would rather use $$\frac{\delta x^{\mu}}{\delta \omega_a} = \frac{x'^{\mu} - x^{\mu}}{\omega_a}$$?

Comment: @Ting-Kai Hsu FIrst, what kind of transformation are the coordinates undergoing? Let me know. Are the $x^\mu$ and $\mathcal F$ defined to be functionals are or they something different?

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus In the book, it says $x'^{\mu}$ would be a function of $x^{\mu}$. I think $x^{\mu}$ would be function of $\omega_a$, and $\mathcal{F}(\Phi(x))\equiv\Phi'(x')$ thus it is functionals. However, the book doesn't give more information , the idea in my previous comment is from the example given in the book.