# Meaning of the notation $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta \alpha}$ in QFT and the Standard Model by Schwartz

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, notation, noethers-theorem, variational-calculus

In equation (3.24) of QFT and the Standard Model by Schwartz, he uses the notation $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta \alpha}$ in the context of Noether's theorem(s) and their applications. I did my Master's dissertation on Noether's theorem last year, and I often saw this notation being used, without any clarification on the difference between this and a regular partial derivative and I was wondering if someone could please explain to me if there is any significant difference and how I should interpret this?

I know that this notation is used in the context of functional derivatives in the Calculus of Variations, but here we simply have a field $\phi$ which is not a functional.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/795811/2451

Comment: In this, global (rigid) case, with *α* a parameter, it *is* a plain partial derivative.

Comment: @CosmasZachos thank you for the reply, so does that mean the only time it will matter is if we have $\alpha(x)$ as local function? If so what is the meaning of the change in notation?

Comment: In such functional maneuvers, there is something to be said about a unified notation; one might get more feckless questions the other way.

Comment: @CosmasZachos agreed, when this notation is used in this context, it is never clear to me as to what the motivation behind it is.

Comment: The motivation may be uniformity of notation, in anticipation of local symmetries...

Comment: @CosmasZachos but why does the consideration of local symmetries require a change to this notation?

Comment: Because *α(x)* is a function, not a parameter.

Comment: @CosmasZachos but we also have derivatives w.r.t $\phi$ and $\partial_\mu\phi$, which are functions, and those are indicated with partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, and? maybe you could amend your question to explain your point.

Comment: @CosmasZachos well my point is clear, what is the meaning of $\frac{\delta \phi}{\delta \alpha}$ how does it differ from when we write $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi}$, what is the need for the change in notation?

Comment: You'd be happier with  *From Classical to Quantum Fields* by  Baulieu,  Iliopoulos, &  Seneor...

Comment: @CosmasZachos thanks for the recommendation, I'll check it out

Comment: @user362295 Could we not define a function as $\phi (x)=F[\phi (y)]=\int\phi (y) \delta (y-x)\; dy$? In this sense any function is trivially a linear functional so that a unified notation is possible. I have always wondered if this were the reason for such notation.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I have never thought about it like that, but it seems like a nice resolution to the problem.